# Using nlminb to maximize functions

Tags: r, function, optimization, maximization

I have the following function  and i need it to be maximized instead of minimized.

```
adbudgReturn = function(Spend,a,b,c,d){
adbudgReturn = sum(b+(a-b)*((Spend^c)/(d+(Spend^c))))
return(adbudgReturn)
}

FP_param <- c(95000,0,1.15,700000)
FB_param <- c(23111.55,0,1.15,20000)
GA_param <- c(115004,1409,1.457,2000000)

y = c(0.333333,0.333333,0.333333)

TotalSpend <- function(Budget,y){
                   FP_clicks = adbudgReturn(Budget * y[1], FP_param[1], FP_param[2],  FP_param[3], FP_param[4])
                   FB_clicks = adbudgReturn(Budget * y[2], FB_param[1], FB_param[2],  FB_param[3], FB_param[4])
                   GA_clicks = adbudgReturn(Budget * y[3], GA_param[1], GA_param[2],  GA_param[3], GA_param[4])
                   return(total = FP_clicks + FB_clicks + GA_clicks)
}




startValVec = c(0.33333,0.333333,0.3333333)
minValVec = c(0,0.2,0)
maxValVec = c(0.8,1,08)


MaxClicks_optim.parms <- nlminb(objective = TotalSpend,start = startValVec,
                     lower = minValVec,
                     upper = maxValVec,
                     control = list(iter.max=100000,eval.max=20000),
                     Budget = 10000)
```

I have tried adding the minus sign in front of the nlminb function i.e:

```
-nlminb(..)
```

but without any success. Any help will be appreciated.

*Also i would like to add constraints so the sum of the maxValVec = 1*

Comment: Hello, i have tried that already and it didn't work. I get the following error:Error in -TotalSepnd : invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: ok, can you please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: minimise the negative of your objective

Comment: Whats than mean exactly? Can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 3):

Other optimization functions in R such as `optim()` have a built-in `fnscale` control parameter you can use to switch from minimization to maximization (i.e. `optim(..., control=list(fnscale=-1))`, but `nlminb` doesn't appear to. So you either need to flip the sign in your original objective function, or (possibly more transparently) make a wrapper function that inverts the sign, e.g.

```
max_obj <- function(...) -1*TotalSpend(...)
MaxClicks_optim.parms <- nlminb(objective = max_obj, 
           [ .... everything else as before ... ] )
```

Note that the `...` in the `max_obj()` definition are literal.  The only part of the solution above that needs to be filled in is the `[.... everything else as a before ...]` part.  To be absolutely explicit:

```
max_obj <- function(...) -1*TotalSpend(...)
MaxClicks_optim.parms <- nlminb(objective = max_obj,
                 start = startValVec,
                 lower = minValVec,
                 upper = maxValVec,
                 control = list(iter.max=100000,eval.max=20000),
                 Budget = 1e4)
```

If you were using a user-specified `gradient` argument you'd have to wrap that too.

[This CV question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331695/maximization-of-a-function-with-nlminb-in-r) points out that you can maximize by minimizing the negative of a function, but doesn't go into the nuts and bolts.

An `optim()`-based solution would look something like:

```
optim(fn = TotalSpend,
      par = startValVec,
      lower = minValVec,
      upper = maxValVec,
      method = "L-BFGS-B",
      control = list(maxit=100000, fnscale=-1),
      Budget = 1e4)
```

- L-BFGS-B is the only method built into to `optim()` that does box-constrained optimization
- `optim()` doesn't have separate controls for max iterations and max function evaluations

Comment: Hello @Ben, thanks for your reply. Is this what you meant, because its not working either:max_obj <- function(x){
  
  -1 * x
}

MaxClicks_optim.parms <- nlminb(objective = max_obj(TotalSpend),
                                start = startValVec,
                                lower = minValVec,
                                upper = maxValVec,
                                control = list(iter.max=100000,eval.max=20000),
                                Budget = 10000)

Comment: no, that's not what I meant.  The first line (objective function definition) should be entered *exactly as written here*

Comment: I'm  not sure i understand, can you give an example please?

Comment: Can you please share an example with optim()

Comment: Hi Ben thank you for your answer. Is there a way using optim() to add constraints. So the sum of the maxValVec parameters will not exceed 1, say. Basically distributing the budget variable between the three parameters so the parameters equal 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with a simple parabolic function, It works the same with `nlminb`and `optim`:

```
## ==== Some preliminaries ========================
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
a <- b <- seq(-10, 10, 0.1)

## ==== Search for a minimum ======================

# function has minimum
f1 <- function(a, b) {
  (a - 1)^2 + (b - 2)^2
}
## show function, blue color is low
image(a, b, outer(a,  b, f1), col=topo.colors(16))

## wrapper: combine parameters
g1 <- function(p) f1(p["a"], p["b"])

## minimization
(ret <- nlminb(c(a=0, b=0), g1))
## show minimum
points(t(ret$par), pch="+", cex=2)


## ==== Search for a maximum =======================

## function has a maximum
f2 <- function(a, b) {
  - (a - 1)^2 - (b + 2)^2
}
## brown color is high
image(a, b, outer(a,  b, f2), col=topo.colors(16))

## wrapper:  combine parameters, invert sign
g2 <- function(p) -f2(p["a"], p["b"])

## minimization of negative objective = maximization
(ret <- nlminb(c(a=0, b=0), g2))
## show maximum
points(t(ret$par), pch="+", cex=2)
```

[image: optimization landscape]